# Use custom svg for next and previous arrow button in the ng-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, svg, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I have custom SVG images that I'd like to use in the ng-bootstrap datepicker to replace the default previous and next buttons.

As a user of this Angular 2 component. I'd like to do this in my own code either overriding or extending one of the Components.

My first step was to use these SVG images as Angular 2 components. I am able to do that in my own app and components. But I do not have direct access to the HTML rendering the datepicker, therefore I am having trouble to use these custom SVGs inside the ng-bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the current version of `ng-bootstrap` doesn't support custom arrow buttons in date picker.

The only way of customization that I see is overriding CSS that renders them: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/d88c8b7391bb42c4bdae24652bc529616c90fa8c/src/datepicker/datepicker-navigation.ts#L18-L35

You can make your custom SVG as a background image from CSS but I think you'll lose "hover" effect for it (if you have some).